# Laravel Carbon data missing when date is an empty string

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

In my model I have the following:

```
protected $dates = ['start_date'];
```

I am using an input field of type 'date' to select the date. If the user removes the date, its value becomes a null string "".
when updating my model, I get the following error:

```
exception: "InvalidArgumentException"
file: "C:\www\projects\crm\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Carbon.php"
line: 582
message: "Data missing"
```

I can avoid this error by using a mutator like this:

```
public function setStartDateAttribute($value)
{
    if ($value) {
        $this->attributes['start_date'] = $value;
    } else {
        $this->attributes['start_date'] = null;
    }
}
```

**Question:**
Is there a faster/better way than using a mutator to deal with storing an empty string as a date?

Comment: Are you using `Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $time, $tz);` somewhere?

Comment: I didn't use it explicitly, but Laravel does when setting the field as a date (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators).

Comment: I haven't come across that before.  In one app I have a number of date fields.  They re marked nullable in the migrations and listed in the dates array on the model.  It all works correctly without needing mutators.

Comment: can you try `\App\Yourmodel::find(7)->update(["your_date_field" => ""]);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into this a bit deeper:

**Middleware updated in 5.4**

Laravel 5.4 included two new middleware in the default middleware stack: `TrimStrings` and `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull`.

> These middleware will automatically trim request input values and
>   convert any empty strings to `null`. This helps you normalize the
>   input for every request entering into your application and not have to
>   worry about continually calling the `trim` function in every route and
>   controller.

From: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/releases#laravel-5.4

So, when I am grabbing the request object, an empty date field is converted to null.  The database allows null on these fields and everything works correctly.

So, through the front end, date fields can be entered and removed without error.  When updating manually to an empty string as per your request

```
\App\Yourmodel::find(7)->update(["your_date_field" => ""]);
```

I had the same `data missing` error.

Question is, do you specifically need to pass an empty string or is making the field nullable a better option for you?

```
\App\Yourmodel::find(7)->update(["your_date_field" => null]);
```

Comment: This makes it all clear now. The reason I have an empty string from the front end, is that I'm wrapping my data in a FormData variable to upload a file to the server. I tried split the file and the datafield data and send a request with two variables (array + file) to the server, but unfortunately I get only the array.
`axios.post('/api/controller/update/' + this.id, {fd: formData, data: this.data})`